# How to keep a Switch thumb shadow/elevation when using a custom drawable for the thumb?

Tags: android, user-interface, shadow, android-elevation

I need to remplace the default Switch thumb with my own drawable. To do so I used the android:thumb attribute, it works well minus the shadow under the thumb is no longer present. How can I use my custom thumb drawable while keeping the thumb shadow/elevation ?

Here's the style I implemented :

```
<style name="TiimeGreenSwitch" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_green_thumb</item>
    <item name="trackTint">@color/switch_green_track</item>
</style>
```

The drawable is this selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_green_thumb_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_green_thumb_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_green_thumb_default" />
</selector>
```

And each drawable look like this :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/switch_checked" />
</shape>
```

Edit: Following Gabe Sechan answer I implemented a shadow directly in the drawable as follow, it works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="22dp"
                android:height="22dp" />
            <solid android:color="#22000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/switch_checked" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the shadow in the drawable.  That's how it works in the default drawable, which is why you lost it now.  Its really the only way to do it, as the OS doesn't know the shape you're actually using and could at best put a shadow below the entire drawable, which would be wrong if you used a circle or rounded edges.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I edited my question with an implementation of your answer.